# How to use ggplot style of matplotlib with agg backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, jenkins

My problem is as follows:

I have a script running remotely via a Jenkins job.
This script is making plots and saving them with `plt.savefig()`

Without the following line on the top of my imports, I can not run my scripts from jenkins:

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

The moment I added this, I could no longer have the ggplot style on my plots:

This line:

```
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
```

is giving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot.py", line 5, in <module>
    matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style'
```

NOTE that:

- this style was working **locally** when I was executing the script without the line `matplotlib.use('Agg')`
- And the script runs normally on jenkins without the ggplot style.

How can I have both on a remote server?

(python 2.7.6, matplotlib 1.4.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`style` is a package that can be imported from `matplotlib.pyplot`, not directly from `matplotlib`.

So, try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
matplotlib.pyplot.style.use('ggplot')
```